# Ubuntu 20.04 not pausing processes (high fan spin/battery drain) on sleep mode

Tags: suspend, power-management, battery, fan

It seems like sometimes when put into sleep mode, the computer is not correctly pausing processes, even though the screen turns off. I will pick up the computer 30 minutes later and the fans are spinning quickly and the battery is draining.

I'm not sure how to diagnose or where to start with solving it. Hardware is Ryzen 4500u in an HP Envy x360 laptop.

Comment: Same with an HP x360 1040. Did you solve?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a Ubuntu 20.04 running on a new HP Omen with Ryzen 7 4800H CPU.
To fix it, I upgraded the kernel to 5.6.0-1023-oem:

```
sudo apt install linux-oem-20.04
```

Then reboot. No need to upgrade all the way to kernel 5.8 (although that one will work, too, but it is harder to install and won't work with secure boot).
It takes about 25s(!) to go into suspend mode after the lid is closed!