# CPU and fans keep working in suspend mode in Ubuntu 20 on Dell Inspirion 5530

Tags: 20.04, suspend, dell, power-management

After adding an SSD to my Dell Inspirion 5530, installing Ubuntu 20 on it and booting from it, suspend doesn't seem to work anymore. Either closing the lid, or running `sudo systemctl susped` would result in screen and keyboard going blank, but the fans noticeably keep working and the laptop keeps being warm.

I tried the following without success:

1. Updated `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` values to `suspend` per [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/05/lid-close-behavior-ubuntu-20-04/)
2. Disabled "Wireless Radio Control", "Trusted Execution" and "Intel Software Guard Extensions" in BIOS per [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1245797/511005)
3. Upgraded kernel to 5.6.19 per [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1271665/511005)

Nothing helped so far. Any help would be appreciated.

P.S.
Log info:

- `sudo blkid`: https://pastebin.com/ZqKsn152
- `cat /etc/fstab`: https://pastebin.com/N31a3sNd
- `cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`:  `No such file or directory`
- `free -h`: https://pastebin.com/iU4H5Zcw
- `swapon -s`: https://pastebin.com/d8CpWsig
- `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`: `1.17.1`

Comment: Did you ADD an SSD, or REPLACE an existing HDD with a SSD?

Comment: I added an SSD, and made it the bootable device (while leaving the HDD in place and reformatting it)

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab` and `cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` and `free -h` and `swapon -s`. When you're done, start comments to me with @heynnema so I get notified.

Comment: @heynnema added

Comment: Thanks. It all looks good so far. Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`.

Comment: @heynnema added

Comment: BIOS is good. What brand SSD?

Comment: SSD: Kingston 500GB

Comment: Go to the kingston web site and check for a firmware update. See https://www.kingston.com/unitedstates/us/support/technical/ssdmanager. Windows required.

Comment: Looks like I already got the latest version. Running `udisksctl  status` I get `KINGSTON SA2000M8500G, revision: S5Z42105`. https://www.kingston.com/en/support/technical/ksm-firmware-update shows `S5Z42105` to be the latest revision

Comment: Well, you've been great about responding to my questions... but I'm out of ideas... sorry. Oh wait... I just thought of one more thing...

Comment: In your BIOS, is there a setting for the disk subsystem that defines "performance" or "compatibility" or some such?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to a kernel version that needs updating as answered in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1270095/ubuntu-20-04-not-pausing-processes-high-fan-spin-battery-drain-on-sleep-mode)

Comment: I tried updating the kernel version to 5.6.19, unfortunately that didn't help

Answer (score 0):

I would check the BIOS settings. I had such problem because in BIOS I had ACPI suspend type: suspend disabled